# How do I get the avatar of a specific user using his user id with discord,py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I used `discord.py` to make a bot that stores the user ids in its database to identify them but I can't figure out how to get the avatar of a specific user just by using their `id`. I searched around and found about something like this - `Client.get_user()` but it doesn't work for me as I couldn't understand it's working from the documentation. Is there any way I can pick up a user's id string from my database and pass it through a function to get that user's avatar and use that in an embed?

I found another question on StackOverflow like mine but the solution in that one doesn't work for me as well.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [article](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#image-data), you get the user's `id` and request the avatar data of the user. It looks like `string`. Here is the sample JSON response from the request:

```json
{
  "id": "80351110224678912",
  "username": "Nelly",
  "discriminator": "1337",
  "avatar": "8342729096ea3675442027381ff50dfe",
  "verified": true,
  "email": "nelly@discord.com",
  "flags": 64,
  "premium_type": 1,
  "public_flags": 64
}
```

Now when you get this: `"avatar": "8342729096ea3675442027381ff50dfe"`, you know that the avatar data is `8342729096ea3675442027381ff50dfe`. After that, you will use Image Base Url for images: `https://cdn.discordapp.com/`.
To request an image you have to chose format (jpg, gif, png etc...). So your final request should be:

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/{user_id}/{user_avatar}.png
```

where `user_id` and `user_avatar` are variables to be changed. For example:

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/80351110224678912/8342729096ea3675442027381ff50dfe.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id='id that you get from database(must be integer)')` then you can get the avatar with `user.avatar_url`. Here is an example do this:

```
user_id = "get the user id from database"
user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, id=int(user_id))
avatar = user.avatar_url
```