# Get discord avatar using user id in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

I am making a script in javascript which takes JSON file of data that has discord accounts' id. is there is a way that i automate the process of fetching all the user data from the id only just like how discord.id do?

I tried using discord apis as [discord.js.org](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL) and followed some videos but nothing seems to work for me.
I am not using discord bot, i just want a plain javascript code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933979/discord-get-user-by-id and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783768/how-do-i-get-the-avatar-of-a-specific-user-using-his-user-id-with-discord-py

Comment: Thanks, but both are using discord bots, I am just running a script. I found a code that might help but it needs my account's token to run and fetch the data...

Comment: What about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69056380/)?

Comment: As he mentioned I must run a `fetch request` which needs to be authorized AKA "bot" and this bot must have a server in common with the targeted id.
Other than that it gives me `{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}`
if it worked for you please quote the code- thanks